# Google Maps does not display on Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement google maps on bootstrap.

I've followed Google's own guide, here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

Whilst this works on a standalone page, when I add the Bootstrap CSS the map doesn't show. I can't seem to find a hack that fixes it.

HTML:

```
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
```

Script:

```
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

CSS (over bootstrap)

```
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

See here for jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robmc/6BTjE/2/

Has anyone encountered this before? I must be missing a basic workaround but no amount of forum searching has helped.

Thanks

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

Comment: And you also need to set the map canvas width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be a Bootstrap issue. For the fiddle you need to use `document.ready`, and the external resource "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&extension=.js"

http://jsfiddle.net/6BTjE/8/

Also, there is no reference bootstrap in your fiddle. Here is a demo with Google maps and Bootstrap...

<kbd>[**Bootstrap + Google Maps**](http://bootply.com/62653)</kbd>

You can see the jQuery `document.ready` in the JavaScript...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 // code here
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand the change to external resource; could you explain how I would implement the document.ready in my HTML markup, or would I need to edit jquery.js?

Comment: Ok, thanks, I must still be missing something. When I update the external resource, and copy and paste the code as you have it into a clean HTML file, it still doesn't work. Is something else loaded that I can't see?

Comment: Does your HTML file include jquery?

Answer (score 5):

I've fixed the issue by changing the height to px. hope it helps

```
#map-canvas{
    /*height: 100%;*/
    height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

//I did this , it worked for me

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var height=$( document ).height();
    $("#map").css("height", height );
});

$( document ).resize(function() {
    var height=$( document ).height();
    $("#map").css("height", height );
});
```